# Writing variable patterns in Isabelle/ML

Tags: isabelle, ml

I was studying ways to trasnlate:

```
apply(rewrite in "_ / ⌑" some_theorem)
```

into ML, and I came up with the following:

```
apply(tactic ‹
   let 
    val pat = [
      Rewrite.In,
      Rewrite.Term (@{const divide(real)} $ Var (("c", 0), \<^typ>‹real›) $ 
                      Rewrite.mk_hole 1 (\<^typ>‹real›), []),
      Rewrite.In      
    ]
    val to = NONE
   in
    CCONVERSION (Rewrite.rewrite_conv @{context} (pat, to) @{thms juanito_def}) 1 
   end
  ›)
```

here I am saying "please pattern match with any subterm of the term in the quotient". You may see previous edits of the question to see interesting patterns.

Some interesting conclusions of having used the library are

- at : allows to select a subterm in which to pattern match
- in : allows to specify all the subterms of a term
- terms will be pattern-matched with the resulting patterns.

**Not understood**

Could you give an explanation of what the following tactic is doing?

```
lemma
  assumes "Q (λb :: int. P (λa. a + b) (λa. a + b))"
  shows "Q (λb :: int. P (λa. a + b) (λa. b + a))"
  apply (tactic ‹
    let
      val (x, ctxt) = yield_singleton Variable.add_fixes "x" \<^context>
      val pat = [
        Rewrite.Concl,
        Rewrite.In,
        Rewrite.Term (Free ("Q", (\<^typ>‹int› --> TVar (("'b",0), [])) --> \<^typ>‹bool›)
          $ Abs ("x", \<^typ>‹int›, Rewrite.mk_hole 1 (\<^typ>‹int› --> TVar (("'b",0), [])) $ Bound 0), [(x, \<^typ>‹int›)]),
        Rewrite.In,
        Rewrite.Term (@{const plus(int)} $ Free (x, \<^typ>‹int›) $ Var (("c", 0), \<^typ>‹int›), [])
        ]
      val to = NONE
    in CCONVERSION (Rewrite.rewrite_conv ctxt (pat, to) @{thms add.commute}) 1 end
  ›)
  apply (fact assms)
  done
```

The first Rewrite.Term and the fixing of a variable are a bit obscure to me.

Comment: actually i just discovered that it is sufficient to use at, so only a pattern (no in)

Comment: I am not familiar with the implementation details of `rewrite`. However, having had brief glance at the ML code, it looks to me as if `subst_parser` plays an important role in what is passed to `rewrite_export_tac` and, hence, `CCONVERSION`. It looks to me as if you are trying to ignore/bypass this stage in your attempts to construct a tactic. Is `pat_ctxt` not important? Are you sure that the raw term used in the method is the same as the term that is passed to `rewrite_conv`? I am certain that if you debug `subst_parser`, you will be able to figure out how to implement something suitable.